# JqGrid : Checkbox formatter

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid, formatter

I'm trying to apply the checkboxes on my columns. All i want to know is how to check or uncheck the boxes depending on the values. For example, check the box if the column's value is '1' however the box is must unchecked if the column's value is '0' or 'null'.

The code below is the part of my whole jqgrid code.

```
coleModel[{
    name: 'MENU1', 
    index: 'MENU1', 
    editable: true, 
    sortable: false, 
    search: false, 
    edittype:'checkbox',
    editoptions: { value:"1:0"},
    formatter: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
        if (cellValue == '1') {
            return 'Enabled';
        }else if(cellValue == '0') {
            return 'Disabled';
        }else{
            return cellValue;
        }
    }
}]
```

This column is showed 'Enabled' or 'Disabled' in list very well. 
I have no idea how to showing the check marks. Please let me know how to do it. Thank you.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

sorry for the wrong question. It is hard to describe to me. Uhm.. could you guys reference the website "http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing". The picture below the 'editGridRow'. The column named 'closed' is what i'm looking for.
I'm not an expert in this field so i can't explain clearly. so sorry.

Comment: Do you want to replace the texts `'Enabled'` or `'Disabled'` to checkboxes. Why you not just use the standard `formatter: "checkbox"`?

Comment: @Oleg because i added the CRUD on the list so the texts 'Enabled' and 'Disabled' is replaced. otherwise the columns are showed as checkboxes when create or update. Those texts are only showed on the Grid List.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. You asked the question about **formatter** which works to place cell content (the content of `<td>`) during filling the grid. It has no relation to editing of the grid. Sorry, but it's absolutely unclear what you want. What you mean under "create or update"? What you mean under "the list" or the "Grid List" ? Is it rows of the grid?

Comment: @Oleg sorry for the wrong question. I've made the jqGrid list to get the values from database and then added the functions 'CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete)' with 'navbuttons' so that i can create or update the records in new poped up page when click the buttons. My point was that the checkboxes should show only in the poped up page. not in the list. sorry it's too complicated..

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand which relation have checkboxes to navbuttons. You posted some code fragment and what to change it, but I have still no idea what changes you want to do. What "poped up page" you mean? Do you mean editing dialog or you make redirection to another HTML page? Do you need chechboxes in Add/Edit form editing dialog? Do you want to hold your custom formatter which display "Enabled" and "Disabled" texts? Do you have problem with the state of checkbox in form editing dialog?

Comment: Which input values have the column "MENU1"? Is it only the values 0 and 1 which you displays as "Enabled" and "Disabled" or it could be *another input values*?

Comment: @Oleg uhm...I am really sorry for bothering you. I edited my question under the original question. Could you please read again?

Comment: @Oleg yes. The "MENU1" column has the values only 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very difficult to understand you because you use existing terminology in a wrong way. Formatter will be only used to place data in the grid cell based on input value. For example you used *custom formatter* in your code which place the string "Enabled" in the column if the input data is "1" and it places the string "Disabled" in the column if the input data is "0".

From the late discussion in the comments to your question I could understand (I hope that now I understand you correctly), that you have just problems with the usage of `edittype: 'checkbox'` in the edit form.

It's important to understand that editing form will be build based on the values from the column. If you use the custom formatter which placed "Enabled" or "Disabled" in the column then you can use

```
edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "Enabled:Disabled" }
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid3__.htm) demonstrates the solution.

Another gut rule would be to define always [unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) together with the formatter. For example you can use the following in combination with your existing `formatter` code

```
unformat: function (cellvalue) {
    switch (cellvalue) {
        case "Enabled":
            return "1";
        case "Disabled":
            return "0";
        default:
            return "0";
    }
},
edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "1:0" }
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid3___.htm) uses the code.

One more option is to remove custom formatter. If the input data need be replaced to the string then you can use [predefined](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) `formatter: "select"`. In the case the definition of the column will contains the following properties

```
formatter: "select", formatoptions: { value: "0:Disabled;1:Enabled" },
edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "1:0", defaultValue: "1" }
```

Because all predefined formatters defines unformatter too, then the `value` option of `edittype: "checkbox"` will be `"1:0"`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid3.htm) uses the properties and the the look of jqGrid is the same as in previous demos.

I personally find one thing not logically. You display "Enabled" or "Disabled" in the grid, but you use checkbox in the editing form. It seems to me not consequent. Either you should use `formatter: "checkbox"` in the grid too and to place the checkboxes in the grid or you should use `edittype: "select"` instead of `edittype: "checkbox"`. In the last case the user will works only with texts "Enabled" and "Disabled".

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid3_.htm) displays select (dropdown) with the values "Enabled" and "Disabled" in the editing form:

[image]

Comment: @홍의숙: You are welcome! Please try to formulate your question more clear next time. You will get the answer more quickly.